# anchored PopupWindow and SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE android

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a PopupWindow anchored at a Button (on top). The PopupWindow contains a ScrollView.
The PopupWindow is in SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE mode and positionned with offsets

Code :

```
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    window.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
```

Screen :

[base screen http://imageshack.us/a/img38/7771/basescreen.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img38/7771/basescreen.png)

When the soft Keyboard appears, I have this (the top Button is hidden) :

[what i have screen http://imageshack.us/a/img21/6396/whatihavescreen.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img21/6396/whatihavescreen.png)

And I would like to have :

The PopupWindow is anchored at the Button and also resized.

[what i have screen http://imageshack.us/a/img805/3302/whatiwantscreen.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img805/3302/whatiwantscreen.png)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what is possible solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Own effort ...
It's not the best solution I've developed but anyway ... it works ...

**Part 1 :** Resize the PopupWindow when the SoftKeyboard appears

- Use the OnGlobalLayoutListener on the content view

  ```
  contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

      int baseHeight = 0;

      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
          if(resized) {
              return;
          }
          if(baseHeight <= 0) {
              baseHeight = contentView.getHeight();
              return;
          }

          final int diff = baseHeight - contentView.getHeight();
          if(diff > 0) {
              // keyboard is visible
              window.update( - 1, baseHeight - diff - yPos);
              resized = true;
          }
      }
  });
  ```

When you've done with this, the PopupWindow stays resized even if the SoftKeyboard is hidden. The GlobalLayout event is not fired because the PopupWindow is smaller.

**Part 2 :** Use a fake PopupWindow to know if the SoftKeyboard is hidden (dirty :()

- Build the fake PopupWindow with the real PopupWindow height
- Don't forget to dismiss the fake when the real one is dismissed
- Show the fake before the real one

  ```
  buildFakePopupWindow(rootHeight);
  window.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

      @Override
      public void onDismiss() {
          if(fakeWindow != null) {
              fakeWindow.dismiss();
          }
      }
  });
  fakeWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
  ```
- Register a GlobalLayoutListener on the fake

  ```
   final View fakeContentView = fakeWindow.getContentView();
  fakeContentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

      int baseHeight = 0;

      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
          if(baseHeight <= 0) {
              baseHeight = fakeContentView.getHeight();
              return;
          }
          final int diff = baseHeight - fakeContentView.getHeight();
          if(diff <= 0 && resized) {
              window.update( - 1, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              resized = false;
          }
      }
  });
  ```

**I'm pretty sure that is a dirty solution but I didn't find another way to do it.**

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, there was an easier solution : `showAsDropDown`. 
This method does the job when the softkeyboard appears ...

The only thing to change in comparison with `showAtLocation` is the xoff and yoff calculation.